# Blob URL could not be loaded

Tags: javascript

below is the javascript code to generate blob url. but when i see the img:src in browser inspect element it says "Could not load image". what may be reason for this?

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.responseType = "json";
        oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
        oReq.open("POST", "bloburl");
        oReq.send();
    
    function reqListener () {
          
          console.log(this.response);
          
          var arrayBufferView =  new Int16Array(this.response); 
          
          
          console.log(arrayBufferView);
          let blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView], {type : 'image/png'});
          
          let img = document.querySelector('img');
          
            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            img.height = 100;
            img.width = 100;
            img.onload = function() {
                URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
              } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

var arrayBufferView =  new Int16Array(this.response);

the above line was replaced with below and it worked for me

var arrayBufferView =  new Uint8Array(this.response);